# Apache is not interpreting .PHP files

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php5

I recently downloaded OpenSUSE OS version 11.4 from the site to use it as a server..In order to do that I downloaded the server edition that has Apache/2.2.17 and PHP5 downloaded by default.....Ok till now it is fine

Now I started the Apache successfully and put a test.php file in the documentRoot directory.
test.php contain only `<?php phpinfo() ?>`

Then using my browser I typed `http://localhost/test.php`
and here was the problem 
the browser didn't display what `phpinfo()` should display, instead it asked me whether I want to open or save test.php...which is driving me crazy....
I googled a lot but no solution

THis is /etc/apache2/conf.d/php5.conf

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php4
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php5
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .php4s
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .php5s
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    DirectoryIndex index.php4
    DirectoryIndex index.php5
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you post your httpd.conf ? The part for PHP only not all of it.

Comment: ok just a minute

Answer (score 4):

One thing worth trying, is verifying that your project is not in a user dir (public_html folder), or that the configuration in php5.conf (/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf for some configuration) allows such interpretation.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    #<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    #    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
    #        php_admin_value engine Off
    #    </Directory>
    #</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check what's inside

```
nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf
```

also you can check

```
sudo dpkg -S php5 | grep libapache2-mod-php5
```

which shows whether you have php5.conf in mods-enabled

I've got there:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Note that this regexp matches .php5, but for some reason could not match .php.

**Solution**

```
apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php5 ; apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php5; apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

then open

```
nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
```

1. and replace

   ```
   <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
   ```

   with

   ```
   <FilesMatch ".+\.ph((p[345]?)|t|tml)$">
   ```
2. or simply execute

   ```
   sudo perl -pe 's|\Q.ph(p[345]?\E|.ph((p[345]?)| if $. <= 3'  /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf
   ```

and restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PHP documentation and make sure the configuration is right

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

This should be in your httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I can't find libphp5.so on my whole system, but i found mod_php5.so

Comment: @Ala ADUDEEB try with this. Make sure your file php5.conf is included in your default conf

Comment: php5.conf is in /etc/apache2/conf.d which is used by default by apache so this is not the problem

Comment: @AlaABUDEEB are you sure using the right php5.conf file? try to find where it's. $ find / -iname php5.conf

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have no apache2-mod_php installed.
Try to `zypper install apache2-mod_php5` or whatever package name `zypper search apache | grep php` shows you.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like mod_php5 is disabled somehow

try (as root)

```
a2enmod php5
service apache2 restart
```

Then try to access the pages again

Comment: I did, but it writes "php5 already exists"

Answer (score 0):

apache modules in suse/opensuse are enabled from /etc/sysconfig/apache2, include php module where needed, run SuSEconfig and restart apache2 service :)

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout#openSUSE_and_SLES_.28Apache_httpd_2.2.29:

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution to the same problem. Change the following directive in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. I still need to understand why this changed the behavior of Apache, but it worked for me.

Change this:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

To this:

```
<Directory />
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `php5` to a line thta starts with
`APACHE_MODULES="actions alias auth_basic authn_file authz_host authz_groupfile authz_user autoindex cgi dir env expires include log_config mime negotiation setenvif ssl userdir reqtimeout authn_core authz_core"` at  `/etc/sysconfig/apache2`.