# how to get the server to process the php file instead of the browser?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apache is not interpreting .PHP files](https://serverfault.com/questions/286882/apache-is-not-interpreting-php-files)

All the tutorials which i found gave me all the information about php and how to go about it.But php code which i type is getting parsed by the browser and not the server.

I have installed apache2 on a ubuntu11.04 system.

Please guide me on how to run the php script on the server(on request from a client)

- Php beginner

Comment: PHP is not processed by browsers, it's processed server-side.

Comment: When you say parsed by the browser, do you mean that you see PHP code displayed in your browser instead of the expected output?  If so, it sounds like you do not have the PHP module loaded or configured properly in Apache, or possibly not using a file extension registered with Apache to process PHP.

Answer (score 2):

[Read this](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies), top to bottom, one of the steps also tests the installation (puts a php file in the correct place).