# Apache: PHP scripts not executing when running 7.0

Tags: php, apache-2.4

**NOTE:** This is **not** a duplicate of, nor is the answer here: [Apache is not interpreting .PHP files](https://serverfault.com/questions/286882)

---

On my local Apache webserver, and I have PHP 5.6 and 7.0 installed. When I run 7.0 the scripts are not executed (just raw text is displayed), but when I switch to PHP 5.6 everything is fine.

I've checked my `httpd.conf` when running 7.0, and it's correct:

`LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php70/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`

Typing `php --ini` in terminal produces the following:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini
```

Which looks correct.

Typing `apachectl -v` produces:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 20 2016 20:03:19
```

I feel like it's an issue with my Apache config.

Comment: @Iain Please read the entire post, not just the subject line. It's a different issue.

Comment: It is the same issue, it also has the same solution.

Comment: @Iain Did you link to the wrong question by mistake? There is no accepted solution on that page, and there is no unaccepted solution on that page that solves the issue I had, either.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! It looks like `httpd.conf` was missing an important line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

For some reason it didn't cause problems with PHP 5.6, but it not being there caused problems with PHP 7.0. Strange.

Comment: If you had used search (above right) you would find that this is a duplicate multiple times over.

Comment: @Iain I did that, there is not a duplicate of this issue (earlier version of PHP executing scripts fine, current version not).